# How to check OpenLdap PasswordPolicy related errors and operational attributes via Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openldap, spring-ldap

We are using spring-security 3.2.3 version to authenticate and access OpenLdap in our application. I am having issues access the PPolicy attributes and errors via Spring context. It is PasswordPolicyAwareContext.

```
<bean id="contextSource  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.ppolicy.PasswordPolicyAwareContextSource">
<constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />     
<property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />   
<property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDN}" />
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityLdapTemplate"  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userDetailsContextMapper" class="LdapUserProfilePopulator"/>
```

- In my Service class, I authenticate using the :

  AuthenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userid, password));
- When there is an error e.g.Password_Expired, Account_Locked it throws exceptions.
- In order to check if the Account is locked etc, I check if the exception is an instance of org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException etc

Question:

1. How do we check the PPolicy errors elegantly and use PasswordPolicyErrorStatus?
2. Also, how do we access the OpenLdap operational attributes including pwdMaxAge, pwdExpireWarning?  I have extended the - LdapUserDetailsMapper to map the LdapContext attributes to my User object but I am not able to get a handle on the operational attributes in ldap.

Truly appreciate any feedback/pointers in this regard!
Thanks!

---

I did the following to handle the specific ldap errors:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/115236-why-passwordpolicyawarecontextsource-doesn-t-throw-exception-for-expired-passwords

i.e extended PasswordPolicyAwareContextSource.java and handled the exception.
I am posting so in case anyone else is looking for similar issue can benefit.
If anyone else has better way of handling please post it.
Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have answered (1) already yourself.

Comment: Hi @EJP thanks for the reply. I am currently doing the foll:                        `catch (Exception exception)
 ` { 
  if (exception instanceof `org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException)
   `{
    `throw new BaseException("Account Locked", exception);
   `} ....                                                                                how do we use the PasswordPolicyErrorStatus instead?    thanks!

Comment: Can anyone please point me to any reference/documentation on how we can get LDAP attributes such as pwdMaxAge,pwdExpireWarning etc via Spring?